# Calculating Transmission with Beer-Lambert Law

Tags: optics

**Introduction**

I am trying to use Beer Lambert's Law to calculate the transmission through a lossy material with the following extinction coefficient (k).

[image: Extinction coefficient of material(k)]
Based on my knowledge, Bouguer's law or Lambert's law of absorption is as follows:

P = Poexp-αx,
α = 4πk/λ,
T = P/Po,

where P is incident power, P is transmitted power, α is absorption coefficient, x is optical length, k is extinction coefficient, λ is wavelength and T is transmission.

The transmission data I am trying to obtain is as follows:

[image: Theoretical Transmission] *Figure 2: Graph of Theoretical transmission*

**Problem**

I have the data for all the terms in the equation, and solving for Transmission, I obtain the following result:

[image: Calculated Transmission]

However, this seems to be an upside down version of the theoretical transmission. This has led me to question the legitimacy of the extinction coefficient, which I calculated with a Fresnel Equation.

**Question:** By looking at the equation, is there a way to confirm that the transmission data calculated from the equation is always the extinction coefficient flipped about a horizontal axis?

Hence, in order to get the theoretical transmission data in Figure 2, is it necessary to flip the extinction coefficient data about a horizontal axis?

Thank you for your attention. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: The transmission will be higher when the extinction coefficient is lower.  So I think your expectation is wrong.